# Why do I get "undefined has no properties" even though I am checking with Optional chaining (?.) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
const result = {
  "records": [
    {
      "recordid": "15986521",
      "sf_Parent ID": "10156246",
      "sf_Created Date": "2022-11-30 17:04:45",
      "sf_Status ID": "64521",
      "sf_Type ID": "64551",
      "cf_txtSourceRecordID": "15986054",
      "sf_Level Two ID": "15986521"
    }
  ]
}

//statement that works
if(result && result.records && result.records.length > 0) {
  const getLatestDACCodesID = result.records[0]["sf_Level Two ID"]; 
  console.log('getLatestDACCodesID ',getLatestDACCodesID); 
}

//trying to achieve the same result with Optional chaining (?.)
//statement that doesn't works when my result = {};
if(result && (result?.records)[0]?.["sf_Level Two ID"]) {
  const getLatestDACCodesID = (result?.records)[0]?.["sf_Level Two ID"]; console.log('getLatestDACCodesID ',getLatestDACCodesID); 
}
```

Comment: Both of them works here

Comment: Statements with Optional chaining (?.) doesn't work when result = {}.

Comment: Because it's `records` which is `undefined`. Should be `result.records?.[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `records` that can be `undefined`

```js
const result = {}

if (result && result.records && result.records.length > 0) {
  const getLatestDACCodesID = result.records[0]["sf_Level Two ID"];
  console.log('getLatestDACCodesID ', getLatestDACCodesID);
}

if (result.records?.[0]["sf_Level Two ID"]) {
  const getLatestDACCodesID = result.records?.[0]["sf_Level Two ID"];
  console.log('getLatestDACCodesID ', getLatestDACCodesID);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
result?.records?.[0]?.["sf_Level Two ID"] ?? "default"
```

Comment: `??` would be better than `||` most-likely

Comment: I agree, edited